# Getting bad user password exception while reading PDF document using iTextSharp - But the document is readable to every one

Tags: .net, itext

I am trying to read PDF document using iTextSharp.

The PDF is open for all to read/print. But it is protected with a password for all other actions.

When I am trying to read PDF I am getting "bad user password" exception.

Could you help me to fix it and treat these kind of PDFs as valid.
Existing security settings for the document are mentioned below, please let me know if I need to give any other permissions on document.

**Security Method:**Password Security
**Document Open Password:** No
**Permission Password:** Yes
**Printing:** High Resolution
**Changing the Document:** Not Allowed
**Commenting:** Not Allowed
**Form Field Fill-in or Signing:** Not Allowed
**Document Assembly:** Not Allowed
**Content Copying:** Not Allowed
**Content Accessibility Enabled:** Not Allowed
**Page Extraction:** Not Allowed
**Encryption Level:** 128-bit RC4

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a sample pdf to reproduce your issue.